# NetBeans can't run Java Client with GlassFish5. Why?

Tags: netbeans, glassfish, ejb

I've been searching an answer for 3 days and without any result :-(.

I created an EJB project with NetBeans (Session Beans + Remote Client). I successfully deployed it on GlassFish5 on my REMOTE server.
But when I started my ClientApp in NetBeans it displayed an error. I looked it up in GlassFish Server, and it told me that ClientApp couldn't find Libraries.

Ok, but I am sure that the Libraries exist! How come?

P.S.
I use Java EE 8, NetBeans 15 and GlassFish 5.1.0 and Java idk 17.0.2 for NetBeans

Log from the Server:

[image: Log entry]

My Project:

[image: Project details]

Comment: Update your question to specify your exact versions of NetBeans, Java and GlassFish. And please don't use bold font for emphasis in your question - it's completely unnecessary.

Comment: Your problem is that you are using JDK 17, but GlassFish 5.1 only supports the use of JDK 8. So you can regress NetBeans to use a version which supports JDK 8 (NetBeans 12.5 is the most recent), or you can upgrade GlassFish to use a version which supports JDK 17 (i.e. GlassFish 6.2.5). Also see [What glassfish version is suitable for jdk 10](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74081487/2985643) for more information on version compatibility between NetBeans, Java and GlassFish.