# What glassfish version is suitable for jdk 10

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

I am trying to setup netbeans 15 for Java development but the glassfish installed could not be added. The wizard asked me to create domain manually on command prompt but while trying to do that I got the error message:

> glassfish requires version 6 but your jdk version is 0.

I have ensured my environment variables are well set

Comment: Java 10 went out of support in September 2018. Use a supported version like Java 8, 11, 17 or 19.

Answer (score 1):

It is tricky to ensure that you are using an appropriate version combination of  NetBeans, Java and GlassFish. I don't know of any single piece of documentation that helps, but this is what you can do:

- Refer to the Release Notes for your NetBeans installation (e.g. [Downloading Apache NetBeans 15](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb15/)) to determine which Java versions it supports.
- Refer to the [Eclipse GlassFish documentation](https://glassfish.org/download) to determine which Java versions GlassFish 6.x supports.

In your case, although you don't mention you GlassFish version, since you are using NetBeans 15 you must use a JDK >= 11. [From the Release Notes for NetBeans 15](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb15/):

> The Apache NetBeans 15 binary releases require JDK 11+, and officially
> support running on JDK 11 and JDK 17.

So your current NetBeans environment which uses JDK 10 is invalid. GlassFish is not your biggest concern; you need to update NetBeans to use a valid JDK first.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73299930/2985643) summarizes GlassFish 6.x <=> JDK compatibility. If you are using a GlassFish release < 6 then you must use JDK 8 which is not supported by any recent release of NetBeans.

And regardless of all that, unless you have a compelling reason for doing so, you should stop using JDK 10. It is unsupported, may present security risks, and is definitely problematic for a working NetBeans/Java/GlassFish environment. Once you have installed a valid JDK, also ensure that you remove all traces of JDK 10 from your environment.

One stable combination you might consider is NetBeans 15 + JDK 11 + GlassFish 6.1, but there are plenty of other possibilities.

Update your question if you still have problems after upgrading your JDK.